# In tensorflow probabiliy, is there a vanilla "Dense" bijector?

Tags: tensorflow-probability

For example, consider a bunch of layers "a traditional keras model". One might put a prior on the weights, a prior on the data in or out. If the Dense network is a bijector, a lot of stuff is handled magically. Looks like Affine and some other layers will allow one to build this manually. There is DenseVariational but that uses a surogate posterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional `Dense` layer is not bijective. `tfb.Affine` with a `scale_tril` parameterization (and optionally a `shift` to act like a bias) is the bijective equivalent.
Can you say more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: That basically answers my question ... I guess I was asking if there was a convenience wrapper for this but basically it is probably best to construct these layers and activations explicitly from the base bijectors.

Is that the pattern that you see the framework is pushing us towards?

Comment: And to be more specific, was look to define a conditional distribution Y|X, for example Normal with mu(X) and sigma(X) being networks with priors on the weights.

Comment: I think the operational point I may have been missing is that with bijectors and transformed distributions, everything is cheap and free *until* you multiply or add two distributions together and that event in the graph basically creates a harder integration problem ... hence variational layers etc.

Comment: If you want to define a hierarchical distribution, you might like the JointDistribution classes, e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_coroutine.py#L81

Comment: You can use bijectors functionally e.g. `tfb.Affine(shift=shift_shaped[...,:n], scale_tril=tfb.ScaleTriL()(scale_shaped[...,:n*(n-1)//2]))(activations_shaped[...,:n])`

Comment: did `tfb.Affine` get deprecated?